# Dataset Error : There is no row at position 0

Tags: .net, ironpython

I'm very confused on this error and not sure where to continue looking.. The below code, grabs a customer list, iterates over said list calling main() if the customer has no entries listed in the database search (value = 0 on COUNT).

This worked FINE last week, yet today with minimal changes (Commented SQL query), throws the IndexError on select customers (Not All) when all listed datasets I've reviewed in break points have rows with Index[0].

I am also not even calling any rows at this point, it throws the exception on main(self, customer) and customer is a string.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'storageInvoicing.xaml')

        self.databaseHead = 'db'
        self.databaseDet = 'db'

        customerList = invoiceQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(custno) from db order by custno")

        #self.invoiceNumber = invoiceQuery("SELECT TOP 1 invoicenumber FROM db order by invoicenumber desc")
        self.invoiceNumber = invoiceQuery("SELECT TOP 1 invno FROM db ORDER BY invno DESC")

        self.invoiceNumber = str(self.invoiceNumber.Tables[0].Rows[0][0])

        self.start_time = time.time()

        self.startDate = '10-28-2019'
        self.endDate = '11-03-2019'
        self.gstRate = 0.10

        for i in range(0, len(customerList.Tables[0].DefaultView)):
            customer = customerList.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]
            customer = customer.replace("'", r"''")
            invoiceCheck = invoiceQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) from db where custno = '%s' and invoicedate = '%s'" % (customer, self.endDate))

            if invoiceCheck.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0:
                if invoiceCheck.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] == 0:
                    try:
                        self.main(customer.strip()) ## THROWS EXCEPTION HERE ##
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)

        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - self.start_time))
```

The below is straight from locals during a customer it throws the error on:

customerList has a total of 3334 data rows as seen in the locals>
[3334]      DataRow

invoiceCheck has a total of 1 rows as seen in the locals>
[0]     DataRow

All current datasets in memory have an index of 0 or greater, but I still receive the error on self.main(customer.strip())

EDIT:

Changing the date range, effects the list of customers that throw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this, turns out it was an issue with the data in SQL, dropping and reimporting the table fixed the issue.